# What's the problem with my code , that returns empty plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am new to Python , and I know is somehow a basic question but has taken my time for a while.

I have table with four columns as `date, time, flow, dayType` which show how many cars pass some area in specific times in two days(`2018-10-05` ,`2018-10-12`) .

Now I want to plot the corresponding flow of each day base on the time on same plot(axes) to compare these days , but the only things I get is an empty plot without showing any diagram!

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from numpy import split
%matplotlib inline
sns.set()
data = pd.read_excel('friday_frame.xlsx', names=['date', 'time', 'flow', 'dayType'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
dataPivot = pd.pivot_table(data, values='flow', index='time', columns='date').plot()
plt.ylabel('flows');
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to make a dummy-DataFrame, similar to what you're doing:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(data={"date": ["01/01/2019", "01/01/2019", "01/02/2019", "01/02/2019"],
                          "time": [pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=1, hour=9),
                                  pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=1, hour=13),
                                  pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=2, hour=9),
                                  pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=2, hour=13)],
                          "flow": [1,2,3,4], "dayType": ["morning", "morning", "afternoon", "afternoon"]})
dataPivot = pd.pivot_table(data, values='flow', index='time', columns='date'); display(dataPivot) #Pivot Table Values
dataPivot.plot(kind="bar") #The Graph
```

It outputs this:

[image: Output of above code]

**What is different here than what you are doing?**

A couple of things, but nothing major.

First, `plot()` needs some `kind` of graph to plot, in this case I chose bar (`kind="bar"`). Of course, you can choose whatever works for you.

Second, I chose to not chain arguments together so I could see my table and my plot. Since I ran this in Jupyter, I needed to use `display` to show more than one thing in a cell.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for your attention , but I still have some problem , now I think it because the flow for some times is missing , I mean e.g I have flow for 2019-05-01 like 4340 but this time for 2019-12-01 I have nothing